# C# arreglos vs Python listas

Tags: c#, python

En python las listas podian contener otras listas por ejemplo

```
    lista = ["x",["a","b"],["c","d"],"z"];
print lista[1][1]>>>>>>>>>> output "b"
```

mi pregunta es... en c# se puede contener en un arreglo otros arreglos y que a su vez contengan elementos sueltos como el de la "x" y la "z" de la lista de python?

estuve probando arraylist y cuando uso

```
miarreglo.AddRange(otro_arreglo);
```

lo que hace es juntarme los elemento sin separarlos es decir yo espero espero esto {"x",{"a","b"}} PERO obtengo esto {"x","a","b"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es complicado comparar un lenguaje fuertemente tipado como es `C#` y `Python` que es un lenguaje de script y es más flexible en esas circunstancias, no obstante, podrías conseguir lo que buscas sin problemas en `C#` también:

### 1.- Matrices ([MSDN - Matrices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9b9dty7d.aspx))

En `C#` puedes tener matrices que al fin y al cabo es un array de arrays.

```
int[,] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

### 2.- Listas ([MSDN - List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx))

Puedes usar una lista de arrays, y de ese modo tener tu colección de arrays:

```
List<int[]> lista_arrays = new List<int[]>();
lista_arrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```